# Android - Notification Activity Audio Closing on App Launch

Tags: android, media-player

I am having a small problem with my app. When there is a notification, I play a custom sound. The problem is that while the notification sound is playing and you open the app, it stops audio. Is there any solution to this so it does not stop the audio on app launch. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My app supports api 8 and above.

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context) 
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(adhanTitle)   
            .setContentText("Adhan Time");

builder.setDefaults(2);

builder.setAutoCancel(true);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(252300, builder.build());  

MediaPlayer mPlayer;
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.fajr);  
mPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to play the sound related to the notification via:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#sound
where the URI of your sound is like mentioned here:
http://androidbook.blogspot.de/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html
"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

But Im not sure whether this solves your problem, especially one need to see more sourcecode especially of the notification sending app and the receiving app. Probably your sending app is just finished and gets destroyed. Players like Winamp use an Android Service with foreground option to play sounds in background, so these services needs to show a notifications. But its also not clear, whether this is your usecase.

Comment: It was working fine when I was doing tests, etc. When I published it on the Play Store, now this problem is there. When the application is not signed then it does not do this. Thanks for your help.